# How do I parse a query string that has an embedded '&'?

Tags: php, query-string

In PHP, how would I parse the following query string to get the entire variable "url" which should contain everything after it?

```
http://www.mydomain.com/?c=log&m=index&url=https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.anotherdomain.com&access_token=AAACPpB5pr5gBAJLFZBGaU6SM7UMlGQob7QUBf3aI0DIHrHWtcTGHirS0UrwwDDZBEiIQHeWfkOVCFbEXrFt6TdVlbPrXmV6xyPDI9pPQZDZD
```

`$_GET['url']`  drops everything after 'www.anotherdomain.com' because it encounters another '&'.

The problem is that 'url' is provided by Facebook. 
If I urlencode the entire string, it becomes invalid.
How would I parse 'url' to programmatically urlencode only the piece that needs to be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
 $link = "http://www.mydomain.com/?c=log&m=index&url=";
 $link .= rawurlencode('https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.anotherdomain.com');
 $link .= '&access_token=AAACPpB5pr5gBAJLFZBGaU6SM7UMlGQob7QUBf3aI0DIHrHWtcTGHirS0UrwwDDZBEiIQHeWfkOVCFbEXrFt6TdVlbPrXmV6xyPDI9pPQZDZD';
```

to retrireve the data use

```
  $url_get = rawurldecode($_GET['url']);
```

Comment: Half the point of `$_GET` is that it decodes the data for you. So you don't need to decode it manually.

Comment: Your first chunk of code changes the name of the variable half way through … then changes it back.

Answer (score 2):

The url should be [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode)d before being passed, otherwise it is an invalid query string parameter.